# expand/collpase not all working within created div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to create div and collapse/expand element within each created div.

```
     var i=1;
      $('#addDiv').click(function() {
        var divId="addedDiv"+i; 
        $(".content_body").slideUp(500);      
        $('<div></div>').attr({
            'id' : divId,
            'class' : 'addedDiv'           
      })
      .appendTo('#container').load("content.php");
      $(".content_head").click(function()
      { 
        $(this).next(".content_body").slideToggle(600);
      });
      i++;
    });
```

content.php :

```
<h2 class="content_head" style="background:orange;"> header</h2>      
<div class="content_body" style="background:blue;"> content </div>
```

html :

```
 <input id="addDiv" type="button" value="add div" >
 <div id="container" style="width:500px;height:auto;background:red;"></div>
```

Say 5 div created, the expand/collapse on 1st,2nd and 3rd created div not working well.

How to fix this problem and also how to insert the 'id' of created div into header of each
(e.g. header of 2nd div = header addedDiv2) ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: FYI `<input >` should be `<input />` and `$('<div></div>')` can be `$('<div/>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the click handler for `content_head` before it actually gets loaded. To correct the issue, you need to bind the events *after* it gets loaded by binding the events inside the success callback of `load()`:

```
...
.appendTo('#container').load("content.php", function() {
    $(this).find(".content_head").click(function() { 
        $(this).next(".content_body").slideToggle(600);
    });
});
...
```

Comment: -0.5 ............ but why do it that way? IS there a better way to achieve the same?

Comment: @roXon - Another way would be using `.on()` on `document` object or a higher container. But i think attaching it to the element itself is less heavier.

Comment: IF you ask me, having the click handler in an unenclosed separate `.on` function would make the code more readable and usable. That's why we have the `.on()` method after all. And *"higher container"* should be: `static parent container` to be more descriptive

Comment: Yes, it would be cleaner with `.on()` - But it is likely to be faster otherwise (yes, if you are attaching it to an immediate parent, there's not gonna be much of a difference). Secondly, the above imo makes it clearer (than using `.on()`) as to what the reason for the error was. Part of my intent was to make that clear.

Comment: faster comparing to what test? `.on()` delegates a click handler to any future element to be created (read: `to be added to the document object model`). Reading a `.load()` callback you logically expect to see a function to be executed immediately, after a `success` response, instead you suggest to create click handlers inside an ajax load callback? And saying that there's not a difference from using `document` or `#parent` I think you're not aware of `propagation` That was just an opinion of mine

Comment: @techfoobar - using your solution :the last created div(say 5th div) now can be expanded/collapased and this is not what i'm trying to achieve, but thanks for that. The problem still exist within 1st-4th created divs, where the expand/collapse still not working well.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute this function soon after you load the `div` through JavaScript.

```
$(".content_head").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".content_body").slideToggle(600);
});
```

If that's not possible, use the `$.on()` function.

```
$("body").on("click", ".content_head", function(){
    $(this).next(".content_body").slideToggle(600);
});
```